# REGEX formula to validate number field on Flow screen

Tags: visual-workflow, validation, regular-expressions, screen-flow

I have a number field called "distance" on a Screen Flow. This flow is of type field service flow and not the traditional SF flow.

I am trying to add validation for this number field such that it only accepts 16 digits before the decimal and only 2 digits after the decimal.

[image]

I tried to use : `REGEX(TEXT({!Distance}), "[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}")` to validate. However I get this error when I try to use the flow from Mobile App:

[image]

When I use it without TEXT: `REGEX({!Distance}, "[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}")` I get an error on Save of the flow - `The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect argument type for function 'REGEX()'.`

Please suggest the correct approach to validate this number field.